# How do I make the grid lines on a Windows.Forms.DataVisualization.Charting.Chart scroll with the data?

Tags: charts, data-visualization, mschart

I have a `Windows.Forms.DataVisualization.Charting.Chart` which is displaying a live data feed.

As data appears on the right, data on the left disappears from view. Currently, the labels on the axis at the bottom increase as the data for the X-axis increases. Is there a way to make the values of the labels stay the same and have the gridlines scroll across with them?

Comment: Sounds like the min/max is not being recalculated. How are you removing the oldest samples from the Series? I've never had this issue when plotting a fixed number of real-time values. Maybe I'm not understanding what you are trying to do.

Comment: The data is provided by binding to an `IEnumerable` collection. The collection manages adding / removing the data. The chart is refreshing though it's just that the grid lines stay in the same place but the numbers under those grid lines change. I want the gridlines to scroll with the data.

Comment: mmm .. time for some silly questions. What is the resolution of your X grid? What is the resolution of the data shown? How often does the data get refreshed? Any chance you can add your chart settings to the question?